# treeview tkinter text editor for rows

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I ve been trying to solve an issue in treeview, that being that i want to split a sentence in a cell so that it fits every word.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD6k5.png)

I was thinking that i can add label into each cell or something but it sounds a bit waste of time.

this is my code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
treeview=ttk.Treeview(root)
treeview.pack()
treeview.insert('', 'end', text="hello/n hello agsgs g asg sg s g sd g sd g s gs g sd g sg ds g")
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40)
```